# How to play/pause video depending on visibility with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I want one or more videos to play/pause depending on whether or not they're in the viewport.

I understand this can be achieved with jQuery (and plugins), so I've tried using the `isInViewport` plugin along with the following code, but I receive the error shown below.

## HTML

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/isInViewport.js"></script>
[...]
<video id="video1" src="file.mp4" width="50%"></video>
[...]
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

## JS

```
var $video = document.getElementsByTagName("video1");

if ($video.is(":in-viewport")) {
  $video.play();
} else {
  $video.pause();
};
```

## Console

```
TypeError: $video.is is not a function
```

Comment: You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) - this allows you to listen to when things enter / leave the viewport

Comment: Would be great to see an example of how to use Intersection Observer API with my particular use-case as I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
$('video').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
    $(this)[0].play();
  } else {
    $(this)[0].pause();
  }
}
);
```

Comment: I tried this but the video only played when the page was loaded; and didn't pause when scrolling away (or play from pause when scrolling back into view).

Comment: :in-viewport is not a Jquery selector and needs a plugin.